# show div if variable is not empty

Tags: html, show

I'd like to show this div with a "add to cart" button IF the price contained in $row_thumbs['Listino 9'] is not empty. How can that be accomplished? Jquery?

```
<div id="button" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">    
      <form name="eCart1_1_ATC_<?php echo $row_thumbs["Cod."]; ?>" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?><?php echo (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) && $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] != "")?"?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]:""; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="eCart1_1_ID_Add" value="<?php echo $row_thumbs["Cod."]; ?>" >
      <input type="hidden" name="eCart1_1_Quantity_Add" value="1" size="2" >
      <input type="image" src="images/acquista.png" width="95"  border="0" class="eC_ImageButton" value="Aggiungi al carrello" name="eCart1_1_ATC"></form>     
      </div>
```

Comment: Isnt it better to do in php directly?

Answer (score 1):

uncomment the first line, then the BUTTON will be showed, make sure the script runs on a server and also I would never make spaces  $row_thumbs['ListinoHERE9']

```
<?php

    //$row_thumbs['Listino_9']='cheater';

    if($row_thumbs['Listino_9']!='') {
        echo '<div class="button"> B U T T O N</div>';
    }
?>
<style type="text/css">
.button {
    padding:5px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:orange;

}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.show-div-if-button-gets-clicked').toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<div class="show-div-if-button-gets-clicked" style="display:none;">
    <form name="eCart1_1_ATC_<?php echo $row_thumbs["Cod."]; ?>" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?><?php echo (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) && $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] != "")?"?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]:""; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="eCart1_1_ID_Add" value="<?php echo $row_thumbs["Cod."]; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="eCart1_1_Quantity_Add" value="1" size="2" >
    <input type="image" src="images/acquista.png" width="95"  border="0" class="eC_ImageButton" value="Aggiungi al carrello" name="eCart1_1_ATC"></form>     
</div>
```